# Character not attacking via Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have built an attack using `SpriteFactory`, and simply want to assign the keyboard letter <kbd>A</kbd> as a default attack. I have used `GetKeyUp` for the sole purpose of the character to attack once, and not multiple times like a loop (i.e. `GetKeyDown`). At this stage I have not included any enemies or anything, as i just want the the character to simply attack when I Press <kbd>A</kbd>. I have Included the game object and added the `Attack.cs` but no success. Maybe I am complete missing the point of what I am doing, but some help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Ok so i have tried the below method. Have adjusted the code as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using FactorySprite = SpriteFactory.Sprite;
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {

// you forgot to set name of variable representing your sprite
private FactorySprite sprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprite = GetComponent<FactorySprite> (); // Edited
}
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) 
    {
        sprite.Play("Attack");     
    }
}
}
```

But now have a ''nullReferenceError'' Object reference not set to an instant object?

Comment: The code you posted is a hollow shell that does nothing. You have an `if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))` with nothing in its body, so nothing will happen whether or not the condition is true.

Comment: *doh*!

Sorry im completely new to C#. What needs to be added to initiate the attack?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [`yourSprite.Play("AnimationName");`](http://www.guavaman.com/projects/spritefactory/docs/pages/classes/Sprite-Play.html) to your loop:

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) 
    {
         yourSprite.Play("AnimationName");     
    }
}
```

For this to work you have to add a reference to your sprite to the script, with `GetComponent()`.
Btw, `GetKeyDown` only triggers once for each key-press, you can use this too. (`GetKey()` would fire every frame)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ok so I have done the above, updated the code too and i seem to be getting a nullReferenceError'' Object reference not set to an instant object?

Comment: Do you have an "attack" sprite?